# Flash Triopo speedlight 586 manual

Tags: flash

Does anyone know where I can find a Portuguese version of the manual for the Triopo TR 586 EX speedlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a manual in (Brazilian?) Portuguese for the Triopo TR-980. Perhaps it has some guidance that you can apply to your TR-586EX model.

http://www.equifoto.com.br/files/Manual-Triopo-TR-980.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Desculpe. Given that the only "documentation" I can find on this model of flash is [a Chinese video I can't even load](http://triopo.cn/MediaCenter/yanshishipin/2015/1022/533.html), I'd say your chances of finding an online PDF of the manual in Portuguese are zero.  I couldn't even find an English-language PDF you could run through Google translation.

Comment: The video plays for me. I opened your link and ignored it for a minute and the video started playing.

Comment: Maybe not quite zero ;)

Comment: @MikeW [grin]. I am the queen of the strawman answer. :)